# Fog configuration for OVH's OpenStack Swift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fog, openstack-swift, ovh

Has anyone managed to connect to OVH's OpenStack Swift with the Ruby gem Fog?
They don't have documentation yet and support doesn't consider Ruby and Fog.

I'm getting the errors `auth failed` or `get_version_v2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'` (unexpected json-structure) or other non-verbose errors.

Since I also have no experience with Fog and OpenStack I am lost here.

Comment: yes, I have used ruby fog with openstack swift (not with OVH). Unfortunatly, your question is not very focused. You are in risk of being downvoted. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try to create a complete, minimal, verifiable example only with ruby, (without rails) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this too. Figured it out:

```
require 'fog'

service = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider            => 'OpenStack',
  :openstack_username  => 'USERNAME AKA ID',
  :openstack_api_key   => 'PASSWORD',
  :openstack_auth_url  => 'https://auth.cloud.ovh.net/v2.0/tokens',
  :openstack_region    => 'BHS1'
})
```

GRA1, BHS1, SBG1 are your region options, you need to choose one.

I haven't confirmed the rest of it works yet, I'm just testing things now and I've gotten to this point. Don't rely on me for technical support, it's really something OVH needs to provide (or pay me to do).

Also make sure to create a user account, don't use the "default" storage bucket thing on the non-OpenStack admin page.